# 413 Request Entity Too Large in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, upload, http-status-code-413

i'm running a laravel project in docker, i'm uploading file on amazon s3 but when i upload file bigger than 5mb i get this error

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwheR.png)

i've already edited the nginx.conf file with

```
client_body_buffer_size  400M;
client_header_buffer_size 400M;
large_client_header_buffers 4 400M;
client_max_body_size 10G;
```

Someone can explain me?

Comment: You might need to increase the `max_post_size` variable in your `php.ini`, as well.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter how can i find my php.ini in docker? i don't have any php.ini in none container

Comment: It depends on the distro the image was built using, but for example in Ubuntu it can be found at `/etc/php/7.3/cli`. Another setting to increase in that file is `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: nginx:alpine, you know?

Comment: Does that image have PHP? I don't see any reference in the docs stating it does.